# How can I refresh a Chart Control in zAppDev

Tags: zappdev

I have a chart control and I want to refresh it when a user presses a button, but without refreshing the entire page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your controller action use the following code.

```
FormControls.{YourChartId}.Refresh();
```